# MySQL $row selected how to only show a column's first n characters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE status=1 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $start_from, " . $results_per_page; 
$rs_result = $con->query($sqli);
$row = $rs_result->fetch_assoc();
```

First, I select row:-

```
<?php echo $row['content'] ?>
```

Then, I print the column and I get the desired result. But, I want it show only 100 first characters. Is it possible? Please someone suggest.
I know it can be used as:

```
mysql> SELECT LEFT('foobarbar', 5);
        -> 'fooba'
```

But, I want my result in PHP like:-

```
<?php echo $row(Left['content','4']) ?>
```

or any proper way?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do the LEFT work in PHP code rather than MYSQL code

Comment: use php substr() function based on  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like you suggest in SQL, by creating another column in the output

```
SELECT *, LEFT(content, 100) as short_content
...
```

Or in PHP

```
$short_content = substr($row['content'], 0, 100);
```